# Centos7 - minimal installation: echo $TERM gives me 'linux' and 'tput colors' gives '8'. How to change that?

Tags: centos, vim

I have installed minimal CentOS 7. In the native terminal, there seems no more than 8 colors.

```
echo $TERM
linux
tput colors
8
```

So, how can I get 256 colors support in vim? `vi` version `7.4.160`.

In putty it says `xterm` but I think in native system I don't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that ncurses is installed on your system :
`sudo yum install ncurses-term`

Then, assuming that you use bash, try to add this to your ~/.bashrc :
`export TERM=xterm-256color`

EDIT :

After some researches it appears that it's not possible to have 256 colors support on a native tty without modifying the Linux kernel.

You could take a look at [FbTerm](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fbterm/), but its last release was in 2010.

Comment: So, installing `ncurses-term` does not help?

Comment: It does help if you try to use a terminal emulator on the machine or with putty (or any ssh client that supports 256 colors), but if you're using a native tty, you're stuck with 8 colors I'm afraid.

Comment: OK... so I am stuck I guess. I ask because my Putty just disconnects after some time, even I sent ServerKeepAlive every 60 seconds. For the virtual machine set up in my PC, I fixed the problem by disabling network adaptor power saving, but this time it is not my machine, so I sometimes have to use native tty.